# Some pages can't be updated - post_content field not updating

Tags: pages, post-content

**Background:**

(Site is running most recent version of WordPress on DreamHost.)

This all seems to have started when I tried to get our WordPress site over to SSL. I had a certificate but going to https://example.com would throw a bunch of errors about requesting assets over http (of course). I ended up installing the [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugin to smooth this out and everything seemed fine.

I had previously installed [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) to try to manually resolve the http/https hard-coded values but didn't end up going through with it. Noting it just in case even just doing the "dry run" they offer might have messed something up.

**Problem:**

**I tried to make a change to a page and it wouldn't go through.** This is only happening on specific pages, and not on posts. Funnily enough, I can see via phpmyadmin that the `wp_posts` field `post_modified` is updated, but not `post_content`.

**Attempts to Fix:**

I have cleared oodles of caches (including W3 Total Cache, my own browser, and CloudFlare). I reverted the plugins folder to what it was a few days ago (before the SSL fiddling). **I uninstalled all plugins and reverted to a default theme and tried to update the page in question -- problem persisted even then.**

So basically I am at a loss. I don't want to have to restore the database if there is some configuration gotcha that I am missing.

Thanks for any help, and if I can provide any more information please let me know.

Comment: why do you try to fix mixed content issue with really simple ssl plugin? anyways. are  there any errors/warnings in browser console?

Comment: @Vishwa I used Really Simple SSL because I don't know how else to solve the issue. Conversion to SSL is not something I've dealt with before, plus this particular site is made up of 30+ different plugins and I don't know how to track down all the http requests. I've added the list of errors that comes up _without_ Really Simple SSL activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem (certain pages not updating) had nothing to do with the SSL conversion. **The issue was the `tmp` directory running out of space.** As the site is on DreamHost VPS I was able to clear this directory by restarting the server. Pages are now able to update again.

Additional debugging steps:

- set `WP_DEBUG` and `WP_DEBUG_LOG` to true
- examine `debug.log` which showed PHP warnings:

  - `write failed: no space left on device` and
  - `failed to write session data (files)`

Searching these errors pulled up info about issues with `tmp` directories.

Relevant DreamHost FAQ page: [/tmp directory overview](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216735938--tmp-directory-overview)